# change print text when tap in GMSPoligon. Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, printing, console

I have some GMSPoligon:

```
    let españa = GMSMutablePath()
    españa.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 42.11, longitude: -9.37))
    españa.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 43.94, longitude: -9.55))
    españa.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 43.60, longitude: -1.89))
    españa.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 42.02, longitude: 3.72))
    españa.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 36.16, longitude: -2.65))
    españa.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.10, longitude: -7.28))
    españa.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 42.08, longitude: -6.61))



    let polygonEspaña = GMSPolygon(path: españa)
    polygonEspaña.fillColor = UIColor(red : CGFloat(fillColorRed), green: CGFloat(fillColorGreen), blue: CGFloat(fillColorBlue), alpha: CGFloat(fillColorAlpha));
    polygonEspaña.strokeColor = strokeColor
    polygonEspaña.strokeWidth = strokeWidth
    polygonEspaña.map = mapView
    polygonEspaña.isTappable = true
```

I implemented some delegates:

import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class MapViewController: UIViewController, GMSMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

and some functions

// ###### Click Country

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap overlay: GMSOverlay) {
    print("User Tapped Layer: \(overlay)")
```

// FUNCTION THAT IS NOT WORKING:    print("has clicado en : (GMSPoligon)")

```
}


// #### Find location in console.


func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    print("You tapped at \(coordinate.latitude), \(coordinate.longitude)")
}
```

GMSPolygon works and they are visible on the map, but when i click them. i recieve this text on my console:

LOCATION TAP : You tapped at 52.8075964305343, 16.8773408979177
GMSPoigonTap: User Tapped Layer:  (null) size 7 color UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0.25 0 0 0.05

I want to change this text and recive, the county. if i tap in spain: YOU CLICKED ON SPAIN. if i click on Germany : YOU CLICKED ON GERMANY.

How can i do that?

Thanks at all buddies.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i added this property to my GMSPolygon

```
        polygonEspaña.title = "España"
```

And this function.

```
  func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap overlay: GMSOverlay) {


    print("\(overlay.title)"




Now i receive in my console : Optional("España"
```